# How to use levels from loglevel in std.experimental.logger?

Tags: logging, d

At [std.experimental.logger](https://dlang.org/phobos/std_experimental_logger.html) there are things like:

```
logf(LogLevel.info, 5 < 6, "%s to the sharedLog with its LogLevel.info", "Logging");
```

What is the `5 < 6` thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the condition. If the condition is `false`, nothing is logged.
See the signature here: https://dlang.org/phobos/std_experimental_logger_core.html#.log.3